# Remove last word in cell/string mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this string in a cell in mySQL:

```
Sholmsgatan 1253 18 Helborg
```

Is it possible to delete all text but the last word "Helborg" ?
The word is dynamic so it cannot be static to "Helborg".

Maby i can check for the last whitespace (in front of Helborg) and remove everything in front of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql's string function `substring_index`, note it uses space as a separator, so it will pick last word from string and update in your column

```
update demo set title = substring_index(title,' ',-1);
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88b9c/1)